# Why 5D gauge theory is non-renormalizable?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, renormalization, dimensional-analysis, moduli

1. My question is following "Why 5D gauge theory is non-renormalizable?" Here I treat $5D$ supersymmetric gauge theories.
2. Also I heard Non-renormalizablity of $5D$ gauge theories implies the singularities in instanton moduli space. How this can be possible? Can you give me a reliable explanation?

Comment: Can you cite a reference for 5D non-renormalizability? http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0305208 indicates non-renormalizability is known to be true only for six dimensions and higher.

Comment: You can find relevant material in [first](http://www.unioviedo.es/hepth/people/Yolanda/talks/IFT2014.pdf) about page 11. and there is some comments on [second](http://www-com.physik.hu-berlin.de/talks/lat05/francesco_lattice_05.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the textbook of TASI 2009, section ["Introduction to extra dimension"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1162v1.pdf) 
i can find the answer as follows.

They state that $5D$ or higher dimensional gauge coupling has a negative mass dimension, so the 5d or higher dimensional gauge theory is non-renormalizable.

Comment: That's a perturbative/power-counting argument, but not a proof that renormalization is impossible, I believe. Symmetries and "accidental" cancellations can make naively divergent stuff finite.

Comment: Ok i try to find relevant materials dealing with cancellation of divergent terms in 5d gauge theory. As a student, i think this topic is interesting subject to study in depth. thanks for your mention. ^.^

Answer (score 1):

Concerning OP's 1st question:

- If we scale the gauge field $A_{\mu}$ so that the quadratic term $-\frac{1}{2}{\rm tr}F_{\mu\nu}^2$ in the Lagrangian density $ {\cal L}$ is canonically normalized, then it has [mass dimension](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=mass+dimension)
  $$ [A_{\mu}] ~=~\frac{d}{2}-1,\tag{1} $$
  where $d$ is the dimension of spacetime.
- From the [gauge covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_covariant_derivative)
  $ D_{\mu}~=~\partial_{\mu} \pm i g A_{\mu}, $ it then follows that the
  gauge coupling constant has mass dimension $$ [g] ~=~2-\frac{d}{2},\tag{2} $$
  which is negative if $d>4$, and therefore non-renormalizable in the old perturbative Dyson sense, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/481249/2451) Phys.SE post.