# Why coupling constants with negative mass dimensions lead to non-renormalizable theories?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, dimensional-analysis, interactions

can somebody explain or point to the relating mathematics showing Why coupling constants with negative mass dimensions lead to non-renormalizable theories?

Answer (score 7):

The standard argument goes as follows. For a connected [Feynman diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram)$^1$ the [superficial degree of (UV) divergence](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=superficial+degree+divergence) $D$ is equal to$^2$
$$\begin{align} D~:=~& \#\{\text{$\mathrm{d}p$ in int. measure}\} ~+~ \#\{\text{$p$ in numerator}\}\cr
&~-~ \#\{\text{$p$ in denominator}\}\cr\cr
~=~&  Ld +\sum_i V_i d_i + \sum_f  [\widetilde{G}_{0f}]I_f\cr
~\stackrel{\text{Ref. }3}{=}& \left(\sum_f I_f -(\sum_i V_i -1)\right)d  \cr
& +\sum_i V_i d_i + \sum_f(2[\phi_f]-d) I_f  \cr
~=~&d- \sum_i(d-d_i) V_i + \sum_f[\phi_f] ~2I_f       \cr
~=~&d- \sum_i(d-d_i) V_i  +\sum_f[\phi_f] \left(\sum_i V_i n_{if}-E_f\right)    \cr
~=~& d -  \sum_i \left(d - d_i - \sum_f [\phi_f] n_{if}\right) V_i - \sum_f [\phi_f] E_f\cr
~=~& d  - \sum_f [\phi_f] E_f   - \sum_i [\lambda_i] V_i \cr
~\stackrel{\text{Ref. }4}{=}&  [\text{amputated diagram}]  - \sum_i [\lambda_i] V_i,  \end{align}\tag{1} $$
where

- $d$ is the number of spacetime dimensions;
- $[\cdot]$ denotes the [mass dimension](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=mass+dimension) in units where $\hbar=1=c$;
- $L$ is the number of independent loops;
- $I_f$ is the number of internal lines with a free propagator $\widetilde{G}_{0f}$ in the Fourier momentum space of a field $\phi_f$ of type $f$;
- $V_i$ is the number of vertices of $i$'th interaction type with coupling constant $\lambda_i$, $d_i$ number of spacetime derivatives, and $n_{if}$ legs of type $f$;
- $E_f$ is the number of amputated external lines with a field $\phi_f$ of type $f$.

The formula (1) has in principle a simple interpretation in terms of [double-entry bookkeeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-entry_bookkeeping_system) as follows. Recall that each vertex arises from a dimensionless action term. So instead of debiting the loop momentum variables $p$ [cf. the definition of $D$], we can instead credit [with the opposite sign] the mass dimension of the rest of the Feynman diagram, namely coupling constants and amputated legs [cf. formula (1)].

Let us now return to OP's question. If an interaction vertex, say of type $i_0$, has $[\lambda_{i_0}]<0$, then eq. (1) indicates that we can build infinitely many superficially divergent Feynman diagrams with $D\geq 0$ by using more and more vertices of type $i_0$.  This render the theory [non-renormalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization) in the old Dyson sense.

References:

1. S. Weinberg, *Quantum Theory of Fields,* Vol. 1, 1995; eq. (12.1.8).
2. M.E. Peskin & D.V. Schroeder, *An Intro to QFT,* 1995; eqs. (10.11) + (10.13).
3. [Use my example to explain why loop diagram will not occur in classical equation of motion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270428/2451)
4. [Why do all Feynman diagrams with same number of external legs have the same mass dimension?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/538319/2451)

--

$^1$ We assume that the sources $J_k$ are either stripped from the Feynman diagram or are delta functions in momentum space so that the external legs carry fixed 4-momenta.

$^2$ It is implicitly assumed that the coefficients in front of the kinetic terms in the action are dimensionless. The quantity $[\phi_f]$ is non-negative for $d\geq 2$.

Comment: Notes for later: 1. Q: Can we generalize to _not_ putting $\hbar=1$?  A: $[\cdot]$ then denotes inverse length dimension. Momentum $p$ should be replaced with wavevector $k$. And $[\phi_f]$  should be replaced with $[\frac{\phi_f}{\sqrt{\hbar}}]$. And $[\lambda_i]$  should be replaced with $[\hbar^{n_i/2-1}\lambda_i]$, where $n_i=\sum_f n_{if}$ is the number of legs on a vertex of $i$th type. 2. Q: How about _not_ putting $c=1$ for non-relativistic physics?

Comment: Notes for later: https://userswww.pd.infn.it/%7Eferuglio/Falkowski.pdf p.6: eq. (1.7) blocking/dimless coupling constants. p. 6-7: $\hbar$.

Comment: Notes for later: 1. For a disconnected diagram with $\pi_0$ connected components, the first term $d\to \pi_0d$ is replaced in eq. (1). 2. In QM $d=1$ the scalar field $[\phi]=\frac{d-2}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}$, so $D$ increased with number of external legs.

Comment: Notes for later: $\quad \sum_i V_i ( n_i -2) =2(L-1) +\sum_f E_f $. So at a certain $\hbar$/loop-order, the number of vertices $V_i$ with $n_i\geq 3$ legs (in the amputated correlation function) is finite. 2-vertices (apart from the kinetic terms) contain derivatives. If we assume Lorentz symmetry such 2-vertices are irrelevant $[\lambda_i]<0$. If the kinetic term is unique (e.g. by homogeneity & isotropy), then all other 2-vertices has $[\lambda_i]\neq 0$. It is natural to assume that all relevant or marginal 2-vertices belong to the free (rather than the  interaction) part of the action.

Comment: 5. E. Panzer, PhD thesis, https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07243 Be aware that Panzer's SDOD $\omega=-\frac{D}{2}$ in eq. (2.1.18) is normalized with a factor $-\frac{1}{2}$. Laplacian $(V\!-\!\pi_0)\times(V\!-\!\pi_0)$ matrix. 6. https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0114 Lemma 50. 7. https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5429 8. Bogner & Weinzierl https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3458 Laplacian $V\times V$ matrix. 9. https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.12296 $(+,-,-,-)$. $\rm L$ seems to be missing in eq. (12). Eq. (B1) correct. 10. https://www.osti.gov/etdeweb/biblio/21380826 15. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4764382/11127

Comment: $n$-tree=tree with $n$ conn. comp. Spanning subgraph=touches all vertices. (Touch by vertex is allowed, and is in fact assumed to be the case.) $(n,\ell)$-graph=graph with $n$ conn. comp. and $\ell$ loops. Componentwise 1PI=don't cut into more conn. comp. by removing 1 line. Componentwise 1VI=don't cut into more conn. comp. by removing 1 vertex. (I.e. the notions make sense even if the graph is not connected.) A self-loop $\int\frac{d^dk}{\pi^{d/2}}\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\Gamma(\nu)}{(k^2+m^2-i\epsilon)^{\nu}}=\hbar m^{d-2\nu}\Gamma(\nu\!-\!\frac{d}{2})$ factorizes. Assume no self-loops.

Comment: Amputated not nec. conn. graphs, i.e. each end of a line has a vertex. (Paradigm: Trees are graphs.) SDOD $\omega(G)\equiv D(G)=dL(G)-2\sum_{e\in G}\nu_e$. Future notation: $G\equiv\Gamma$. $\quad k_v=\sum_{e\in E}k_e{\cal E}_{e,v}+p_v$; $\quad{\cal L}^{\prime}:={\cal E}^{\prime T}{\cal A}^{-1}{\cal E}^{\prime}$; $\quad{\cal U}_{0,0}\equiv{\cal U}_0\equiv{\cal U}={\cal K}\det{\cal A}$; $\quad{\cal K}_{0,0}\equiv{\cal K}_0\equiv{\cal K}=\det{\cal L}^{\prime}$; $\quad{\cal F}/{\cal U}={\cal F}_0/{\cal U} +m^T{\cal A}m$; $\quad{\cal F}_0/{\cal U}=p^{\prime T}{\cal L}^{\prime -1}p^{\prime}$;

Comment: $\quad{\cal F}_0/\det{\cal A}=p^{\prime T}\text{Cofactor}({\cal L}^{\prime})p^{\prime}$ $=\sum^{\prime}_{i,j\in V\backslash\{v_0\}}p_i(-1)^{i+j}\det({\cal L}^{\prime}{}^i_j)p_j$; Homogeneity:$\quad[{\cal U}_{n,\ell}/\det{\cal A}]=[{\cal K}_{n,\ell}]=[\alpha^{-1}]^{V-\pi_0-n+\ell}$; $\quad[{\cal U}_{n,\ell}]=[\alpha]^{L+n-\ell}$; $\quad[{\cal F}_{n,\ell}/\det{\cal A}]=[\alpha^{-1}]^{V-\pi_0-1-n+\ell}$; $\quad[{\cal F}_{n,\ell}/{\cal U}_{n,\ell}]=[\alpha]$; $\quad[{\cal F}_{n,\ell}]=[\alpha]^{L+1+n-\ell}$; $\quad [\alpha]=\text{mass dim}^{-2}$;

Comment: Multiple parallel edges (bananas) are allowed. $\quad\frac{\Gamma(\nu)}{k^2+m^2-i\epsilon}=i^{\nu}\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}d\alpha~\alpha^{\nu-1}e^{-i(k^2+m^2-i\epsilon)\alpha}$; Schwinger parametrization (without coupling constant factor $\prod_v\tilde{g}_v $ and traditional physics Fourier factor $(4\pi)^{-dL/2}$). Minkowski signature $(-,+,+,+)$. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/752398/2451

Comment: $\quad I=\left[\prod_{e\in E}\frac{\hbar}{i}\int\frac{d^dk_e}{\pi^{d/2}}\frac{\Gamma(\nu_e)}{(k_e^2+m_e^2-i\epsilon)^{\nu_e}}\right]\left[\prod^{\prime}_{v\in V\backslash\{v_0\}}\frac{i}{\hbar}\pi^{d/2}\delta^d(k_v)\right]$ $=\left[ \prod_{e\in E} \frac{\hbar}{i}i^{\nu_e}\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}d\alpha_e~\alpha_e^{\nu_e-1}\int\frac{d^dk_e}{\pi^{d/2}}\right]\left[\prod^{\prime}_{v\in V\backslash\{v_0\}}\frac{i}{\hbar}\int\frac{d^dx_v}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}\right]\exp(-iS)$

Comment: $I=\ldots=\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\right)^Li^Li^{-dL/2}\left[\prod_{e\in E}i^{\nu_e}\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}d\alpha_e~\alpha_e^{\nu_e-1}\right]{\cal U}^{-d/2}\exp(-i({\cal F}/{\cal U}-i\epsilon))$ non-projective $=\hbar^Li^{-D(G)/2}\left[\prod_{e\in E}\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}d\alpha_e~\alpha_e^{\nu_e-1}\right]\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\!d\lambda~\delta(\lambda\!-\!\sum_{e\in E}H_e\alpha_e){\cal U}^{-d/2}\exp(-i({\cal F}/{\cal U}-i\epsilon))$ linear gauge.

Comment: $I=\ldots\stackrel{\alpha^{\prime}_e=\lambda\alpha_e}{=}$ $\hbar^L\left[\prod_{e\in E}\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}d\alpha_e~\alpha_e^{\nu_e-1}\right]\delta(1\!-\!\sum_{e\in E}H_e\alpha_e)\frac{\Gamma(-D(G)/2)}{{\cal U}^{d/2}}\left(\frac{\cal F}{\cal U}\right)^{D(G)/2}$ projective/scale invariant/Cheng-Wu theorem; (Compare with I&Z eq. (6-91) with $(+,-,-,-)$.)

Comment: $\quad S=\sum_e\alpha_e(k_e^2+m_e^2-i\epsilon) +\sum^{\prime}_{v\in V\backslash\{v_0\}}k_v\cdot x_v$ $=k^T{\cal A}k +x^{\prime T}({\cal E}^{\prime T}k+p^{\prime}) +m^T{\cal A}m-i\epsilon$ $=(k+{\cal A}^{-1}{\cal E}^{\prime}\frac{x^{\prime}}{2})^T{\cal A}(k+{\cal A}^{-1}{\cal E}^{\prime}\frac{x^{\prime}}{2}) -\frac{x^{\prime T}}{2}{\cal L}^{\prime}\frac{x^{\prime}}{2} +x^{\prime T}p^{\prime} +m^T{\cal A}m-i\epsilon$

Comment: $S=\ldots=(k+{\cal A}^{-1}{\cal E}^{\prime}\frac{x^{\prime}}{2})^T{\cal A}(k+{\cal A}^{-1}{\cal E}^{\prime}\frac{x^{\prime}}{2})$ $-(\frac{x^{\prime}}{2}-{\cal L}^{\prime -1} p^{\prime})^T{\cal L}^{\prime}(\frac{x^{\prime}}{2}-{\cal L}^{\prime -1}p^{\prime}) +p^{\prime T}{\cal L}^{\prime -1}p^{\prime}+m^T{\cal A}m-i\epsilon$; For $L=1$ one-loop, choose gauge fixing fct. $\sum_{e\in E}H_e\alpha_e={\cal U}$. Note that kin. ${\cal F}$ drops out if $D(G)=0$ log. div. Period =  Residue of $1/\epsilon$ in log. div. graph with no kin. $\quad P(G)={\rm Res}_{D(G)=0}I(G)=\int\ldots {\cal U}(G)^{-d/2}$;

Comment: Notes for later (old): $k_v=\sum_{e\in E}k_e{\cal E}_{e,v}+\Delta p_v$; $\quad \Delta p_v:=p_v-q$; $\quad I=\left[\prod_{e\in E}\int\frac{d^dk_e}{\pi^{d/2}} \frac{\Gamma(\nu_e)}{(k_e^2+m_e^2)^{\nu_e}}\right]\left[\prod^{\prime}_{v\in V\backslash \{v_0\}} \pi^{d/2} \delta^d (k_v)\right] $ $ =\left[ \prod_{e\in E} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}d\alpha_e~\alpha_e^{\nu_e-1}\int\frac{d^dk_e}{\pi^{d/2}} \right]\left[\prod_{v\in V}\int\frac{d^dx_v}{(4\pi)^{d/2}} \right]\int\frac{d^dq}{(2\pi)^d} \exp(-\widetilde{S})$; $\quad {\cal L}:={\cal E}^T{\cal A}^{-1}{\cal E}$;

Comment: Notes for later (old): $\quad \widetilde{S}=\sum_e \alpha_e(k_e^2+m_e^2) + i\sum_{v\in V}k_v\cdot x_v =k^T{\cal A}k +i x^T({\cal E}^Tk+\Delta p) +m^T{\cal A}m$ $=(k+i{\cal A}^{-1}{\cal E}\frac{x}{2})^T{\cal A}(k+i{\cal A}^{-1}{\cal E}\frac{x}{2}) +\frac{x^T}{2}{\cal L}\frac{x}{2} +ix^T\Delta p +m^T{\cal A}m$;

Comment: $\quad{\cal L}_{ii}=\sum_{e\in i}\alpha_e^{-1}$; $\quad{\cal L}_{i\neq j}=-\alpha_e^{-1}$ if $i\in e\ni j$ else $0$;  $\quad {\cal E}\begin{pmatrix} 1\cr \vdots \cr 1 \end{pmatrix} =0$ $\quad\Rightarrow\quad$ $\det{\cal L}=0$; To show that $\det({\cal L}^1_1)=\det({\cal L}^n_n)$ (for conn. graph) compare ${\cal L}^1_1$, ${\cal L}^{1,n}_{1,n}$,  ${\cal L}^n_n$. Primary $e_0$-sector: $\alpha_e\leq\alpha_{e_0}$. Hepp sectors: $\alpha_{\pi(1)}\leq\ldots\leq\alpha_{\pi(I)}$.

Comment: Assume $D(G)<0$ is UV conv.?? UV-div $k_e\to\infty\Rightarrow\alpha_e\to0$. IR/soft/collinear div. $k_e,m_e,p_v\to0\Rightarrow\alpha_e\to\infty$. Tropical formulas $\quad\alpha_e\equiv e^{\tau_e}$; Tropical $\tau$-function (of graph $G$)$=\sum_{e\in G}\nu_e\tau_e-\frac{D(G)+d}{2}\max{\cal U}_{00}(G)+\frac{D(G)}{2}\max{\cal F}_{00}(G)$; Momentum-IBPs are often more practical than $\alpha$-sector-decomposition.

Comment: UV: Tropical $\alpha$-degree (of subgraph $\gamma$)$=\sum_{e\in\gamma}\nu_e\tau_e-\frac{D(G)+d}{2}L(\gamma)+\frac{D(G)}{2}(L(\gamma)(+1)_0)$ $=-\frac{D(\gamma)}{2}\left(+\frac{D(G)}{2}\right)_0>0$ for UV conv (Gen. case $\neq 0$); IR: (of subgraph $G/\gamma$)$=-\frac{D(G/\gamma)}{2}\left(+\frac{D(G)}{2}\right)_{\neq0}<0$ for IR conv (0 case most important); Test ${\cal F}_{00}(G/\gamma)=0$; (Ignoring gauge-fixing. Panzer seems to argue via the non-projective formula.) Note that SDOD grows if we destroy edges without destroying loops. Hence it is enough to check 1PI subgraphs.

Comment: 3. Dirk Kreimer. UV $\overline{MS}$ Renormalization. https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9607022 $<\ldots>=$div. part p.23. Knot/link p.30. Skein relation p.32. ${}_j\Delta$ p.33. $\zeta(3)$=trefoil p.68. https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9707029 Hopf algebra. $Z=$CT. $\quad-R$=div. part. Forest formula is non-overlapping p.5. https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9810022 Overlapping divergences (OD). https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.06409 Cosmic Galois group. Prop 2.2. Def 3.1 https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.04301

Comment: 4. Overlapping divergencies destroys the paradigm of only needing to renormalizing 1PI vertices and self-energies. Kreimer: "One of the achievements of renormalization theory that it disentangles ODs in terms of nested and disjoint ones." Idea: Does ODs go away in $\alpha$-parametrization?

Comment: Matrix-Tree Theorem: 20. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix 21. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem 22. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula 23. https://julesjacobs.com/notes/kirchoff/kirchoff.pdf 24. https://www.math.brown.edu/reschwar/M1230/cauchy.pdf 25. https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/mark.muldoon/Teaching/DiscreteMaths/LectureNotes/IntroToMatrixTree.pdf No proof but mentions Tutte. 26. https://mathoverflow.net/q/73385 Induction.

Comment: Lagrangian/determinants originally comes from Gaussian integration but polynomials such as Kirchhoff, Symanzik, Tutte, etc, seem to be the right generalization (incl. self-loops). 39. https://www.mathematicalgemstones.com/gemstones/a-linear-algebra-free-proof-of-the-matrix-tree-theorem/ Blog with Zeilberger's idea.

Comment: 40. https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarimY/DM85.pdf complete graph p.67. (Incompleting a graph can destroy but not create loops.) Each vertex in directed graph can only have 1 output (0 if we delete rows). Deleting $v$th row<=>$v\in I$<=>$v$th vertex terminal<=>$v$ has no output. Idea: Introduce $r_{vw}$ with $n=E<w\leq V=n+\pi_0$ for terminal vertices. (Recall that a single vertex is a 1-tree.) Case $I=J$: Each conn. comp. of a spanning tree must have precise 1 terminal vertex $v\in I$. OTOH, $w\in J\backslash I$ is never a terminal vertex, possibly an initial vertex.

Comment: 50. J.W. Moon https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(92)00059-Z Digraph = directed graph. Their "root" is more correctly called terminal element. Thm 2.1: Spanning sub-graph=each dynamical (= not spectator) vertex $v\notin I$ has an output but not nec. an input, i.e. $-s/r_{v\Box}$ is present in each term. So $n$ edges. Each vertex has 0 or 1 output, possibly many inputs. Don't forget that cycles of length $\geq 3$ are directed.

Comment: $\quad\det(M)=\sum_{\pi\in S_n}\sigma(\pi)m_{1\pi(1)}m_{2\pi(2)}\ldots m_{n\pi(n)}$ $=\sum_{\pi\in S_n}\sigma(\pi)m_{\pi(1)\pi(2)}m_{\pi(2)\pi(3)}\ldots m_{\pi(n)\pi(1)}$; $s$-variables comes in cycles only. Each $s$-loop has a minus. Now consider the remaining diag. $r$-variables. Each conn. comp. has 0 or 1 loops. Consider spanning graph $D=B\cup\bigcup_1^{\nu(D)} C$. [Old:Make disjoint partition $R\sqcup S=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ of rows.] $\quad\det(M)=\sum_{\text{directed graph  }D}r(b(D))\prod_{h=1}^{\nu(D)}\{r(c_h(D))-s(c_h(D))\}$. Error: $\nu(D)=$# of cycles rather than conn. comp.??

Comment: Thm 3.1 with $s=r$: The vertex corresponding to the $w$th deleted column must be hit. Spanning graph=each dynamical (=not spectator) vertex $v\notin I$ has an output but not nec. an input. $\quad w\in I\backslash J$ has input but no output. $\quad w\in I\cap J$ has no output; possibly input. $\quad w\in I$ can only sit in second place of $-s/r_{\Box w}$.  $\quad v\in J\backslash I$ has output; possibly input. $\quad v\notin I\cup J$ has output; possibly input. (Ignoring conn. comp. consisting of a single vertex.)

Comment: $\det(M^I_I)=\sum_{D\text{ with terminal vertices }I}r(b(D))\prod_{h=1}^{\nu(D)}\{r(c_h(D))-s(c_h(D))\}$ $=\sum_{|I|\text{-tree }F\text{ with terminal vertices }I}s(e(F))$; $\quad\Gamma\backslash\gamma$ ($\Gamma/\gamma$) is $\Gamma$ where each edge of $\gamma$ is removed (shrunk to a point and its vertices identified), respectively. The quotient can have self-loops. "Double" quotient $\Gamma//\gamma$ is $\emptyset$ if $L(\gamma)>0$. Set deletion may violate mom. cons. (Paradigm: Try to avoid set deletion $\Gamma\backslash\gamma$.) Remove pertinent row/column in Lagrangian.

Comment: $\quad\det(0\times0\text{-matrix})=1$; A single vertex is a 1-tree. $\quad{\cal K}_{n,\ell}(v)=\delta_n^0\delta_{\ell}^0={\cal U}_{n,\ell}(v)$; $\quad{\cal F}_{n,\ell}(v)=0$; Undirected graphs: $\quad{\cal K}_{0,0}(v_1\!\ni\!e\!\in\!v_2)=\alpha_e^{-1}$; $\quad{\cal U}_{0,0}(v_1\!\ni\!e\!\in\!v_2)=1$; $\quad{\cal F}_{0,0}(v_1\!\ni\!e\!\in\!v_2)=p_1\cdot p_2 \alpha_e$; (even for self-loop $v_1=v_2$ if we change loop number $\ell=0\to\ell=1$.)

Comment: $\quad{\cal K}_{n,\ell}(G)=\sum_{\text{span. $(|\pi_0(G)|+n,\ell)$-subgraph }\gamma}\prod_{e\in\gamma}\alpha_e^{-1}$; $\quad{\cal U}_{n,\ell}(G)=\sum_{\text{span. $(|\pi_0(G)|+n,\ell)$-subgraph }\gamma}\prod_{e\notin\gamma}\alpha_e$; $\quad{\cal F}_{n,\ell}(G)=\sum_{\text{vertex pair }i,j}p_i\cdot p_j$ $\sum_{\text{span. $(|\pi_0(G)|+1+n,\ell)$-subgraph }\gamma\text{ with terminal vertices }i,j}\prod_{e\notin\gamma}\alpha_e$; $\quad n,\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$. (If $n,\ell<0$ then it is zero.) Laplacian factorizes in conn. comp.

Comment: Vanishing theorem: ${\cal K}_{n,\ell}(G)=0\Rightarrow{\cal K}_{\leq n,\geq\ell}(G)=0$. Similar for ${\cal U}_{n,\ell}(G)$ and ${\cal F}_{n,\ell}(G)$. If $G$ has no external momenta $p_v=0$ then ${\cal F}_{n,\ell}(G)=0$. If $G$ has no masses, similar story. Scaleless case. $\quad {\cal U}_{n=0,\ell}(\text{tree})=\delta_{\ell}^0$;

Comment: If $G_1\cap G_2\subseteq v$ then ${\cal K}_n(G_1\cup G_2)=\sum_{r=0}^n{\cal K}_r(G_1){\cal K}_{n-r}(G_2)$; $\quad{\cal U}_n(G_1\cup G_2)=\sum_{r=0}^n{\cal U}_r(G_1){\cal U}_{n-r}(G_2)$; $\quad{\cal F}_n(G_1\cup G_2)=\sum_{r=0}^n{\cal F}_r(G_1){\cal U}_{n-r}(G_2)+\sum_{r=0}^n{\cal U}_r(G_1){\cal F}_{n-r}(G_2)$; $\det({\cal L}^{\prime v}_w(G))=0$ if $v$ and $w$ are not connected in $G$.

Comment: Induction: $\quad{\cal K}_{n,\ell}(G)=\theta(e\!\in\!G)\left(\alpha_e^{-1}{\cal K}_{n,\ell}(G/e)+{\cal K}_{n,\ell}(G\backslash e)\right)$ $+\theta(e\!\notin\!G)\left\{\theta(v_1,v_2\!\in\!G)(\ldots{\cal K}_{n-1,\ell}(G/e)+\ldots{\cal K}_{n,\ell+1}(G/e)) +(1\!-\!\theta(v_1,v_2\!\in\!G)){\cal K}_{n,\ell}(G\backslash e)\right\}$ (spanning subgraph $\gamma\subseteq G$: cases $e\in\gamma$; $G\ni e\notin\gamma$; $e\notin\gamma,G$);

Comment: $\quad{\cal K}(G)=\alpha_e^{-1}\theta(e\!\in\!G){\cal K}(G/e)+{\cal K}(G\backslash e)$; $\quad{\cal U}(G)=\theta(e\!\in\!G){\cal U}(G/e)+\alpha_e{\cal U}(G\backslash e)$; $\quad{\cal F}_0(G)=\theta(e\!\in\!G){\cal F}_0(G/e)+\alpha_e{\cal F}_e(G\backslash e)$; $\quad\det({\cal L}^{\prime}(G))=\text{affine in }\alpha_{12}^{-1}=\alpha_{12}^{-1}\det({\cal L}^{\prime}(G/e_{12}))+\det({\cal L}^{\prime}(G\backslash e_{12}))$; The first term adds row 1 to row 2 and column 1 to column 2. For ${\cal F}_0(G)$ induction wrt. $\alpha_{12}$ in  $\det({\cal L}^{\prime n-1}_{n-2}(G))$.

Comment: Assume $G$ connected $|\pi_0(G)|=1$ while $\gamma\subseteq G$ not nec. conn. and might have loops. Then $\quad {\cal K}_{n,0}(G)=\sum_{n',n^"\in\mathbb{N}_0}{\cal K}_{n',0}(\gamma){\cal K}_{n^",n'+n^"-n}(G/\gamma)$; $\quad\bar{\cal K}_{n,\ell}(G):=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N}_0}{\cal K}_{n-m,\ell-m}(G)$ $=\sum_{n',n^",\ell',\ell^"\in\mathbb{N}_0}^{n-\ell=n'-\ell'+n^"-\ell^"}{\cal K}_{n',\ell'}(\gamma){\cal K}_{n^",\ell^"}(G/\gamma)$ $=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N}_0}\bar{\cal K}_{m,\ell}(\gamma)\bar{\cal K}_{n,m}(G/\gamma)$ where $\ell'\leq\ell, n^"\leq n$; UV:$\alpha_{\gamma}\ll1$. IR:$\alpha_{G/\gamma}\gg1$.

Comment: ${\cal K}_{00}(G)-{\cal K}_{00}(\gamma){\cal K}_{00}(G/\gamma)={\cal O}\left((\alpha_{G/\gamma}^{-1})^{V(G/\gamma)}\right)$ only contain less powers of $\alpha_{\gamma}^{-1}$ /more powers of $\alpha_{G/\gamma}^{-1}$. $\quad{\cal U}_{00}(G)-{\cal U}_{00}(\gamma){\cal U}_{00}(G/\gamma)={\cal O}\left(\alpha_{\gamma}^{L(\gamma)+1}\right)$; $\quad{\cal F}_{00}(G)-{\cal U}_{00}(\gamma){\cal F}_{00}(G/\gamma)={\cal F}_{00}(\gamma){\cal U}_{00}(G/\gamma)+{\cal U}_{10}(\gamma){\cal F}_{01}(G/\gamma)+{\cal O}\left(\alpha_{\gamma}^{L(\gamma)+2}\right)={\cal O}\left(\alpha_{\gamma}^{L(\gamma)+1}\right)$;

Comment: Proof: $\quad|\pi_0(G/\gamma)|=1$; $\quad V(G)=V(\gamma)-|\pi_0(\gamma)|+V(G/\gamma)$; $\quad E(G)=E(\gamma)+E(G/\gamma)$; $\quad L(G)=L(\gamma)+L(G/\gamma)$; Let $T\subseteq G$ be a spanning $(n+1,\ell)$-subgraph with $V(T)=V(G)$; $|\pi_0(T)|=n+1$; $L(T)=\ell$; $E(T)=V(G)+\ell-n-1$. Then $\tau=T|_{\gamma}$ is a spanning $(n'+|\pi_0(\gamma)|,\ell')$-subgraph in $\gamma$ [since $V(\tau)=V(\gamma)$ all vertices in $\gamma$ belongs to $\tau$] with $n'=|\pi_0(\tau)|-|\pi_0(\gamma)|\geq 0$; $0\leq L(\tau)=\ell'\leq\ell$; $E(\tau)=V(\gamma)+\ell'-n'-|\pi_0(\gamma)|$.

Comment: And then $t=T/\gamma$ is spanning $(n^"+1,\ell^")$-subgraph $G/\gamma$ with $V(t)=V(G/\gamma)$; $n^"+1=|\pi_0(t)|\leq|\pi_0(T)|=n+1$; $0\leq L(t)=\ell^"$; $E(\tau)=V(G/\gamma)+\ell^"-n^"-1$. $\quad V(T)=V(\tau)-|\pi_0(\gamma)|+V(t)$; $\quad E(T)=E(\tau)+E(t)$; $\quad0\leq\ell^"-\ell+\ell'=L(t)-L(T)+L(\tau)=|\pi_0(\tau)|-|\pi_0(\gamma)|-|\pi_0(T)|+|\pi_0(t)|=n^"-n+n'$; $\Box$

Comment: $G_m$=subgraph of all massive propagators in $G$ (with nec. vertices). $G_p$=subgraph of all external momentum vertices in $G$. Let $\gamma\subseteq G$ be a subgraph. $\quad\gamma$ $m$-cover of $G\Leftrightarrow\gamma\supseteq G_m$. $\quad\gamma$ $p$-cover of $G\Leftrightarrow\gamma\supseteq G_p$. $\quad\gamma$ $p$-connected$\Leftrightarrow\gamma_p\subseteq$ conn. comp. of $\gamma$. $\quad G\backslash\gamma$ IR subgraph of $G\Leftrightarrow\gamma$ $mp$-cover of $G$ and [each conn. comp. of] $\gamma/(G_m\cup G_p)$ is 1PI. (Hm. Speculate whether to replace $G\backslash\gamma$ with $G/\gamma$?)

Comment: $\quad G\backslash\gamma$ IR-irreducible subgraph of $G\Leftrightarrow G\backslash\gamma$ IR and $G/\gamma$ 1VI. $\quad\gamma$ motic$\Leftrightarrow\forall\mu$ proper subgraph that is $p$-connected and $mp$-cover of $\gamma: L(\mu)<L(\gamma)$.

Comment: 30. Relation to resistor networks https://mathoverflow.net/q/364948 $\alpha_e=$resistance in an edge $e$. $\alpha^{-1}_e=$conductance in an edge $e$. Ohm's law $\quad-j_a={\cal A}^{-1}_{ab}{\cal E}_{b,v} U_v$; current conv $\quad {\cal E}_{u,a}j_a=\delta_{u,v}-\delta_{u,w}$; $\quad e_v={\cal L}^{\prime}U^{\prime}$; Resistance $\quad R_{vw}=\frac{\det({\cal L}^{v,w}_{v,w})}{\det({\cal L}^{w}_{w})}$ from Cramer's rule;