# Lifetime of a particle at the maxima of an unstable potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, dimensional-analysis, interactions

Consider an unstable potential of the form $$V(\phi) = - \lambda \phi^n $$ with $\lambda > 0$ (hence unstable). Now due to quantum fluctuations, a particle at the top is going to roll down. So what is the lifetime of the particle at the maxima of the potential?

Nima in his [2019 TASI lecture on EFT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-88tuPoyC0) gives a hand-wavey argument via dimensional analysis in 4D. Particularly, the lifetime $\tau \sim \frac{1}{M}$ where $M$ is the mass dimension of the proportionality constant in the potential. While it works for $n=2,3$, at $n=4$ he derives the lifetime from some other argument to be $\tau \sim e^{1/\lambda}$ . For $n>4$, again this procedure doesn't give the right answer. e.g. for $n=6$, $\tau \sim \sqrt{\lambda}$ which is incorrect/opposite to what you expect.

So is there a way to derive the lifetime in a more concrete way and which works for any power of potential (in any number of spacetime dimensions)?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Note that Nima around 38:07-38:12 changes $\Gamma$ to $\tau=1/ \Gamma$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this answer we generalize the discussion of the unstable potential $$\begin{align} {\cal L}~\sim~&(\partial \phi)^2 - {\cal V}(\phi), \cr {\cal V}(\phi)~=~& -\lambda\phi^n,\cr \lambda~>~&0,\end{align}\tag{1} $$ in the 1st [2019 TASI lecture on EFT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-88tuPoyC0) by Nima Arkani-Hamed to arbitrary spacetime dimension $D>0$ and interaction power $n\geq 2$.

The system is more formally described by quantum tunnelling through a kinetic energy barrier, cf. the semiclassical theory of [false vacuum decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum_decay) by [Coleman](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.15.2929) & [de Luccia](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.21.3305).

We'll find that we are (the system is) always eventually dead (delocalized), but the tunnelling may take longer than the age of the universe.

- [24:30](https://youtu.be/7-88tuPoyC0?t=24m30s) Dimensional analysis of mass dimension $[\cdot]$ in absolute units $\hbar=1=c$:
  $$\begin{align} [\phi]~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~&\frac{D-2}{2}, \cr
  [\lambda]~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~&D-n[\phi] ~=~(1-\frac{n}{2})D+n  .\end{align}\tag{2}$$

  1. [Relevant interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization_group): $[\lambda]>0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{D}>\frac{1}{2}$.
  2. Marginal interaction: $[\lambda]=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{D}=\frac{1}{2}$.
  3. [Irrelevant interaction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/481249/2451): $[\lambda]<0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{D}<\frac{1}{2}$.
- [32:10](https://youtu.be/7-88tuPoyC0?t=32m10s)
  Groundstate wavefunction
  $$ \begin{align}\text{wavefunction}\quad \Psi ~\sim~& \prod_{\bf k} \exp\left( -\omega_{{\bf k}}|\tilde{\phi}({\bf k},t)|^2\right)\cr
  ~\sim~& \exp\left( -\int d^d{\bf k}~\omega_{{\bf k}}|\tilde{\phi}({\bf k},t)|^2\right), \cr 
   [\tilde{\phi}]~=~&-\frac{D}{2},\qquad D~=~d+1. \end{align}$$
- [33:30](https://youtu.be/7-88tuPoyC0?t=33m30s)
  Gaussian wavefunction for bubble of height $\phi_0$ and radius $R$ using dimensional analysis:
  $$ \begin{align}\text{wavefunction}\quad \Psi ~\sim~& \exp( -A), \cr 
  \text{with}\quad A~\sim~&\phi_0^2 R^{D-2}. \end{align}\tag{3}$$
- [35:15](https://youtu.be/7-88tuPoyC0?t=35m15s) Using eq. (3) fluctuations grows $R\to\infty$ (dies $R\to0$) for $D<2$ ($D>2$), respectively.
- [37:00](https://youtu.be/7-88tuPoyC0?t=37m00s) Decay rate for non-marginal interaction $[\lambda]\neq 0$ from dimensional analysis:
  $$\begin{align} [\Gamma]~=~&-[\tau]~=~1\cr
  \Rightarrow\qquad 
  \tau^{-1}~\equiv~&\Gamma~\sim~\lambda^{1/[\lambda]}. \end{align}\tag{4} $$

  Note that a mass-term $n=2$ is a relevant coupling in any spacetime dimension $D$. From now on we assume that $n>2$.
- [43:00](https://youtu.be/7-88tuPoyC0?t=43m00s) The radius $R$ of the bubble should be big enough that the negative potential term overcome the positive kinetic term/surface energy term
  $$\lambda\phi_0^n~\sim~\phi_0^2/R^2\tag{5}$$
  $$\Rightarrow \qquad \phi_0~\stackrel{(5)}{\sim}~ (\lambda R^2)^{-1/(n-2)}\tag{6}$$
  $$\Rightarrow \qquad A~\stackrel{(3)+(6)}{\sim}~  R^{D-2}(\lambda R^2)^{-2/(n-2)}. \tag{7}$$

  1. Relevant interaction: $A$ is a negative power of $R$.
     $$\Rightarrow \qquad A ~\stackrel{(7)}{\to}~ 0\quad\text{for}\quad R~\to~\infty.\tag{8}$$
  2. Marginal interaction: $A$ is independent of $R$:
     $$  A~\stackrel{(7)}{\sim}~  \lambda^{-2/(n-2)} \tag{9}$$
     Non-perturbative in the coupling constant $\lambda$.
     $$\Rightarrow \qquad \Gamma~\stackrel{(3)+(9)}{\sim}~  \exp\left(-\lambda^{-2/(n-2)}\right). \tag{10}$$
  3. Irrelevant interaction: $A$ is a positive power of $R$.
     $$\Rightarrow \qquad A ~\stackrel{(7)}{\to}~ 0\quad\text{for}\quad R~\to~0.\tag{11}$$
     (Note that it is [technically unnatural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalness_(physics)) if all interactions are irrelevant.)

Comment: Notes for later: Replace mass dimension with inverse length dimension.