# Checking if an integral converges (or diverges) using dimensional analysis

Tags: renormalization, dimensional-analysis, integration, singularities

[Cross posted at Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4569703/)

I have been watching some online lectures, and the lecturer uses dimensional analysis to make claims such as the following:

Consider the integral
\begin{equation}
I(\xi, d) = \int_0^\xi \frac{\mathrm{d}^\mathrm{d}q}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{1}{q^2(q^2+1)}\quad\text{where}\quad q=|\boldsymbol{q}|.
\end{equation}

It is claimed that

1. The "measure of the integral" is $\xi^{d-4}$, hence $I$ is a constant for $2<d<4$ in the limit $\xi\to\infty$
2. Using the above, $I$ diverges with $\xi$ for $d>4$
3. When $d=4$ (then"marginal case"), $I\sim\log(\xi)$

I recognise that these claims are imprecise: but that's exactly my question!

1. How is such dimensional analysis used to determine the convergence or lack thereof of integrals in arbitrary dimension $d$?
2. What does the "measure of the integral" mean?
3. Furthermore, how do we know that there is no divergence due to the singularity at the origin?

**EDIT**

I'm accepting Qmechanic ♦'s answer below. For a purely mathematical answer (which I found very clear), see the linked Math.SE cross post.

Comment: Link to online lecture? Which minute?

Comment: Sorry, the lectures are not publicly accessible. The comments are offhand, with no more detail than is given here - hence my confusion!

Comment: What we need isn't so much dimensional analysis as $\mathrm{d}^dq=q^{d-1}\mathrm{d}q\mathrm{d}\Omega$ (though I can see why that's labelled DA), so $I(\infty,\,d)$ diverges due to a $O(q^{d-5})$ integrand for large $q$ provided $d\ge4$, or due to a $O(q^{d-3})$ integrand for small $q$ provided $d\le2$, but converges for $d\in(2,\,4)$. (In fact, if we allow $d$ to be complex in a suitable continuation scheme, the convergence condition is $\Re d\in(2,\,4)$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we try to give a conceptional (rather than a computational) answer to OP's 3 questions:

1. The relevant notion is the [superficial degree of (UV) divergence](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=superficial+degree+divergence) $D$, see e.g. my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/481304/2451).
2. The measure of the integral usually refers to $\mathrm{d}^\mathrm{d}q$. It seems the lecturer instead means that the measure of the integral is $\xi^D$, which is nonstandard terminology.
3. Infrared (IR) singularities from massless fields are often regularized by giving them a small mass. (Also we  assume that the integral has been Wick-rotated to Euclidean signature.) In OP's integral the possible IR singularity is the reason for the mentioned lower bound $d>2$.

Comment: One of the bounds on $d$ for convergence comes from avoiding UV divergence; the other comes from [IR divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_divergence).

Comment: $\uparrow$ Right.