# Is this theory renormalizable? If so, is there any proof?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, dimensional-analysis, klein-gordon-equation

Consider a kinetic lagrangian of 2 Klein-Gordon-Foch fields $\varphi$ and $\chi$ with interaction term

$$\mathcal{L}_I=g^2\bar{\chi}\chi\bar{\varphi}\varphi.$$

Is theory with such interaction renormalizable? Is there any proof?

Comment: In which spacetime dimension?

Comment: Hint: [Dimensional analysis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/481249/2451) shows that it is renormalizable for $d\leq 4$.

Comment: I disagree. That interaction can make a divergent graph with four $\varphi$ legs.